# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Let me start by saying that I've read about 15 similar threads on here and other sites trying to fix my problem before posting.

Im testing a site with some php and mysql. Some info:

I built the site hosted locally, then exported to 000 webhost. Is that even necessary in order to test php and mysql functions? I have a mysql database locally. Would this be causing the problems?

I have two problems.

1. On pages that run any php scripts i get the following warnings:

> Warning: virtual() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/a2575478/public_html/Login.php on line 2
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/a2575478/public_html/Login.php on line 37
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/a2575478/public_html/Login.php on line 37

I know these warnings are related to mysql_* functions being deprecated but am having trouble fixing the deprecated functions

2.

Now, when i try to access the web pages locally, all i get is a "Webpage is not available" error. Is that due to the errors or just trying to run php locally?

The site is reachable [here](http://aaronwanjala.comeze.com/Login.php)

Let me know if you need any more information.

Code below.

Login.php

```
    <?php @session_start(); ?>
    <?php virtual('/Connections/logincon.php'); ?>
    <?php
    if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
    {
      if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
        $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
      }

      $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

      switch ($theType) {
        case "text":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;    
        case "long":
        case "int":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "double":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "date":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        case "defined":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
          break;
      }
      return $theValue;
    }
    }


    $query_Login = "SELECT * FROM `user`";
    $Login = mysqli_query($logincon,$query_Login) or die(mysqli_error($logincon));
    $row_Login = mysql_fetch_assoc($Login);
    $totalRows_Login = mysql_num_rows($Login);
    mysqli_select_db($database_logincon, $logincon);
    ?>
    <?php
    // *** Validate request to login to this site.
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
      session_start();
    }

    $loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
      $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['Username'])) {
      $loginUsername=$_POST['Username'];
      $password=$_POST['Password'];
      $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "UserLevel";
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "/Account.php";
      $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "/Login.php";
      $MM_redirecttoReferrer = true;
      mysql_select_db($database_logincon, $logincon);

      $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT Username, Password, UserLevel FROM `user` WHERE Username=%s AND Password=%s",
      GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

      $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $logincon) or die(mysql_error());
      $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
      if ($loginFoundUser) {

    $loginStrGroup  = mysql_result($LoginRS,0,'UserLevel');

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && true) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="CSS/Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
<link href="CSS/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
<link href="CSS/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="/SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Holder">
<div id="Header"></div>
<div id="NavBar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Login.php">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="Register.php">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="ForgotPassword.php">Forgot Password</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="Content">
    <div id="PageHeading">
      <h1>Home Page </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="ContentLeft">
      <h2>This is a test page for a project in progress</h2>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <h6>A work in progress.   </h6>
    </div>
    <div id="ContentRight">
      <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>">
        <span id="sprytextfield1">
        <label for="LoginForm"></label>
        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
        <table width="400" border="0" align="center">
          <tr>
            <td><h6><span id="sprytextfield2">
              <label for="Username"></label>
              Username:<br />
              <br />
              <input name="Username" type="text" class="StyleTxtField" id="Username" />
              </span></h6>
            <span><span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><h6><span id="sprytextfield3">
              <label for="Password"></label>
              Password:<br />
              <br />
              <input name="Password" type="text" class="StyleTxtField" id="Password" />
              </span></h6>
            <span><span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="LoginButton" id="LoginButton" value="Login" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </form>
    </div>
 </div>
<div id="Footer"> </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield1");
var sprytextfield2 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield2");
var sprytextfield3 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield3");
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Login);
?>
```

Logincon.php, manages the database connection

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_logincon = "172.16.1.72:3306";
$database_logincon = "logindb";
$username_logincon = "root";
$password_logincon = "boombox";
$logincon = mysql_pconnect($hostname_logincon, $username_logincon, $password_logincon) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any replies

Comment: You are mixing drivers. `Mysql_` != `mysqli`. For example `$Login = mysqli_query($logincon,$query_Login)` <-- `mysqli` then ... `$row_Login = mysql_fetch_assoc($Login);` your with `mysql_`then same driver again, `
$totalRows_Login = mysql_num_rows($Login);` then back to `mysqli`,`mysqli_select_db($database_logincon, $logincon);`

Comment: The error says precisely what the problem is

Comment: Replace `virtual(` with `include(`, you can't use `virtual()` anyway (disabled, as the error message says).

Comment: I tried replacing virtual with include

>Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/Connections/logincon.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/a2575478/public_html/Login.php on line 2

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` functions. You can't do that. `logincon.php` needs to use `mysqli_connect`, not `mysql_pconnect`.

```
$logincon = mysqli_connect($hostname_logincon, $username_logincon, $password_logincon, $database_logincon) or trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
```

And in the main script you should use `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`.

```
$theValue = myqsli_real_escape_string($logincon, $theValue);
```

And you have to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and `mysqli_num_rows`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, added all the changes you gave, still having the errors though.

Comment: If `include` is failing, that will prevent the rest of the script from working correctly. You need to figure out why it's not finding the script. Maybe the problem is that it should be `Logincon.php` instead of `logincon.php`.

Comment: Now I'm getting a new set of errors. The problem does seem to be with either the logincon script or the passing of its information:


`Notice: Undefined variable: logincon in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line 11`

Comment: You need `global $logincon;` in `GetSQLValueString` so you can access the global variable, or pass `$logincon` as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just went around changing mysql_* functions to mysqli_* functions. My problem is now between the scripts and my Mysql database. I'll make a new question that's more relevant.

Thanks again for all the help.